# Is there a way to trigger a different scroll speed on an element only when that element is in the viewport?

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I'm working on a website that contains a section with images that scroll at differing speeds.

I have one function that initializes the scroll speeds (this utilizes the transform/translateY attribute), and another function that can trigger other functions when each image moves in/out of the viewport.

However, I'm not sure how to merge the two into one concise function that triggers each image's scroll speed when entering the viewport, locking it's new translateY value once it leaves the viewport.

I also want the translateY value to be based off of the top of the section the images are in, rather than the top of the page.

This seems to be a little over my head, so if anyone can point me in the right direction or has any thoughts, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.pixijs.com and in particular https://www.pixijs.com/tutorials and http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5226

Comment: You might also find it easier to manage in javascript ( as opposed css ) - you can see scrolling code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075030/4779501

Comment: Thanks Bob! Sorry for the delay; been pretty busy at work. I wound up just using standard parallax scrolling.